# validate xml string content including encoding using C#

Tags: c#, xml, validation, encoding, xmldocument

I need to validate a string that contains XML Data, there is no schema validation required. All I need to do is make sure that the XML is well formed and properly encoded. For example, I want my code to identify this snippet of XML as invalid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parentNode> Positions1 ’</parentNode>
```

Using the `LoadXML` method in `XMLDocument` does not work, there are no errors thrown when I load the snippet above.

I am aware of how to do this if the content were in an XML file, the following snippet of code shows that:

```
XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
readerSettings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
readerSettings.CheckCharacters = true;
readerSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.None;

xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFileName, readerSettings);
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(xmlReader);
```

So short of creating a temporary file to write out my xml string content and then creating an `XmlReader` instance to read it, is there any alternative? Appreciate much if someone could guide me in the right direction with this problem.

Comment: There is nothing invalid about the snippet, I am just looking for alternatives to writing the xml data out to a temporary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achim,

Thanks for your detailed replies, I was able to finally come up with a solution that fits my needs. It involves grabbing the bytes out of the 'unicode' string and then transforming the bytes to utf8 encoding.

```
        try
        {
            byte[] xmlContentInBytes = new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(xmlContent);

            System.Text.UTF8Encoding utf8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false, true);
            utf8.GetChars(xmlContentInBytes);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not fully understand what encoding means. If you have a .Net string in memory, it's no more "raw data" and has no encoding for that reason. And so LoadXML ingores for a good reason. So what you want to do makes not much sense at all. But if you really want to do it:

You can convert your string into a in memory stream, so you don't have to write a temporary file. Then you can use that stream instead of the xmlFileName in your call to XmlReader.Create.

Comment: I did suspect that LoadXML is not aware of the encoding mostly because it was probably designed to load xml fragments. A little more background on why I need to do this - we accept XML filings uploaded to a site as well via a web service, this XML data needs to be validated. Do the following steps make sense:

Comment: Do the following steps make sense: 1) Figure out the encoding of the xml data by peeking at the data using a regular expression, 2) Read the bytes using system.text.encoding.[encodingType].GetBytes, 3) Write the bytes to a memory stream and 4) Use the memory stream in the call to XmlReader.Create. I am kind of tied down a bit because there are many pieces of the system that use the XMLDocument representation of the given XML data and I am looking for a most efficient way to validate the data without breaking all other functionality.

Comment: You have to get the difference between a binary representation of a string and the abstract concept of a string. From a users point of view a .Net string does not have an encoding anymore. It's just a string. The decoding that you have in mind has to take place in an earlier step: An HTTP request has an encoding and you have to use that one to decode the string. Or you might pass the request stream to an XDocument. As soon as you have an .Net string, it's usually to late to decode. But in most cases .Net should have handled this for you already. ;-)